# BigQuery resources exceeded

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to transform table with 500M rows, about 30GB. It is simple grouping, the result should be another big table. I'm writing the result into new table with Allow Large Result option enabled - this should allow arbitrary large results but I'm getting Error: Resources exceeded during query execution. Job ID: job_6CHEAHSHETUOGK7QAGSTIX5A4QVV4ZKZ

Could you please check which resources exceeded?

Thanks, 
Radek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your query is hitting a corner case in our configuration -- if it was a little bit larger, it would be fine, and if it was a little bit smaller, it would also be fine.

We've got a fix -- hopefully we can get it out today, but it might have to wait until Monday because of the Thanksgiving holiday this week.